# count and join has to include records in a table that does not exist in another

Tags: mysql, join, if-statement, count

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26ee6

```
SELECT g.gameID, (count(h.idx)%2) as lastmove
FROM games as g
  inner join history as h on g.gameID=h.gameID 
WHERE (g.whitePlayer=2 or g.blackPlayer=2)
GROUP by g.gameID, g.whitePlayer, g.blackplayer
HAVING (g.blackPlayer=2 AND lastmove=1)
OR (g.whitePlayer=2 AND lastmove=0)
```

Preferred RESULTS:

```
gameID--lastmove - really move  - is it player=2 's move ?
256 ---- null --=> white -> player2= white = yes its move => out
414 ----  1 ----=> black -> player2= white   = not
497 ----  0 --- => white -> player2= white = yes its move => out
498 ----  1 --- => black -> player2= black = yes its move => out
```

I am trying to get ALL GAMES where

```
(g.blackPlayer=2 AND lastmove=1) OR (g.whitePlayer=2 AND lastmove=0)
```

Problem is for game 256, there are no records in history.

```
(count(h.idx)%2) as lastmove  returns 0 and that is good
```

but the gameID is not in the Join and therefore 
**gameID=256 is missed completely!**

If i Join the otherway around i can not implement the COUNT without errors, 
and anyway that missed the game 256 as well:

```
SELECT g.gameID
FROM games as g
  inner join history as h on g.gameID=h.gameID 
WHERE (g.whitePlayer=2 or g.blackPlayer=2)
GROUP by g.gameID, g.whitePlayer, g.blackplayer
HAVING (g.blackPlayer=2 AND ((count(h.idx)%2)=1) -error
OR (g.whitePlayer=2 AND ((count(h.idx)%2)=0)  -error
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26ee6

Who can help solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure i understood your problem, but if you want to include game 256, you should do a LEFT JOIN instead of the inner join:

```
SELECT g.gameID, (count(h.idx)%2) as lastmove
FROM games AS g
  LEFT JOIN history AS h ON g.gameID=h.gameID 
WHERE (g.whitePlayer=2 OR g.blackPlayer=2)
GROUP BY g.gameID, g.whitePlayer, g.blackplayer
HAVING (g.blackPlayer=2 AND lastmove=1)
OR (g.whitePlayer=2 AND lastmove=0);
```

In your second query you are missing a couple of `)`.

If you do it with left join it would be:

```
SELECT g.gameID
FROM games as g
  LEFT JOIN history AS h ON g.gameID=h.gameID 
WHERE (g.whitePlayer=2 OR g.blackPlayer=2)
GROUP BY g.gameID, g.whitePlayer, g.blackplayer
HAVING (g.blackPlayer=2 AND ((count(h.idx)%2)=1))
OR (g.whitePlayer=2 AND ((count(h.idx)%2)=0))  ;
```

See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26ee6/50)

Comment: Now i see i really was close, but LEFT join does indeed do the trick !